# angular jqLite error

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день, у меня всплывает ошибка при подклчении сервиса

```
angular.js:13236 Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/jqLite/nosel
    at angular.js:68
    at Object.JQLite [as element] (angular.js:2860)
    at Object.submit (former.js:56)
    at new <anonymous> (employeesimport.js:7)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4604)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9855)
    at Object.link (angular-material.js:1540)
    at linkElement (angular-material.js:2926)
    at angular-material.js:2800
    at processQueue (angular.js:15552)
```

Ругается оно (я так думаю) на вот ету строку в former.js:56

```
var former = angular.element("#former");// <-----------------



function submit(path, data, options) {

                options = options || {};
                data = data || {};

                var options = angular.extend(provider.options(),options);

                if(options.events.begin) {
                    options.events.begin(data,options);
                }

                var url = provider.option('url') + path;

                var former = angular.element("#former");


                var target = '_blank';
                var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;

                var browsers = {chrome: /chrome/i, safari: /safari/i, firefox: /firefox/i, ie: /trident|msie|edge/i};

                for(var key in browsers) {
                    var search = browsers[key].test(userAgent);
                    if (search == true && key == 'ie')
                        target = '_self';
                }

                if(!former.length) {
                    former = angular.element("<form>",{ action: url, method: 'POST', target: target });
                }

                angular.forEach(data,function(value,key) {
                    if (value === Object(value)){
                        appendObject(former, key, value);
                    }else{
                        former.append(angular.element("<input>",{ type: 'hidden', name: key, value: value }));
                    }
                });
                angular.element(document.body).append(former);
                former.submit();
                former.remove();
            }
```

по ссылке которая указана в тексте ошибки http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/jqLite/nosel ничего вразумительного не нашел.

Comment: Рекомендую перевести сообщение об ошибке. Сразу станет понятно, почему "ничего вразумительного", т. е. простого способа это исправить, по ссылке нет.

Comment: ну превод таков: Глядя элементы через селекторы не поддерживается jqLite! типа данные елементы не поддерживаются jqLite но бред, я "спер" данный сервис из другого нашего проекта где не подключалась полная библиотека jQuery

Comment: Там это могло работать по другим причинам, которые мы уже никогда не узнаем. Зато мы точно знаем, почему не работает сейчас.

Comment: Коллега я - не Ванга, спасибо конечно что пытаетесь натолкнуть на мысль, но я пока не понял о чем вы

Comment: Там прямо написано, что jqLite не поддерживает никаких селекторов сложнее имени тега. Никакие ни `id`, ни классы, ни атрибуты, ни порядок, никакие связи между элементами оно не понимает.

Comment: Спасибо, немного прояснили. Буду думать как исправить

Comment: @Кнопкатык, не совсем верно :-) не понимает именно _angular.element_

Comment: @Grundy эм, да, уточнение, **ангуляровский** jqLite :] Блин, хоть бы назвали по-другому. ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказано в ошибке `angular.element` не может *искать* по переданной строке, так как это всего лишь `lite`-версия.

И там же в [справке](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) указано, что заменить поиск по строке можно используя метод `find`. Но проще всего использовать нативные средства поиска типа: [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) и другие, и результаты уже передавать в `angular.element`.

В данном случае хватит `document.getElementById`

```
var former = angular.element(document.getElelementById("former"));
```